# Convert SQL Server Date to mm-yyyy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to convert my Date which is (eg. 2012-04-20 05:54:59) format in  into mm-yyyy. I came across some solutions that says you would need to convert into varchar . Is there any way using the Convert function ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Try `SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105) , 7)`

Comment: I tried this but when I use varchar im not able to sort the date according to the year. for example say I transformed the date from 2015-04-20 05:54:59 to 04-2015, now, since this is in varchar format and say if there are more dates in the column where the dates were : 03-2011,06-2014. and if I sort this column, I will get the following: 03-2011,04-2015,06-2014. Sorting this varchar column doesn't sort the date column.

Comment: Do the sorting on the column as a datetime value, just do this formatting related task to a column you'll use for *display*.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `FORMAT` function, available from SQL Server 2012 onwards:

```
DECLARE @myDate DATETIME = '2012-04-20 05:54:59'
SELECT FORMAT(@myDate, 'MM-yyyy')
```

**Output:**

```
04-2012
```

Comment: Thank you :) . But here you've fed the date in the query. How would I frame the command if I had a date column instead ??? I tried the following, but didn't work : 
DECLARE @myDate (select date from dbo.EOD)
SELECT FORMAT(@myDate, 'MM-yyyy')

Comment: @PrateekDaniels If you want to format a specific column, e.g column [date], of a table then you can do: `select FORMAT([date], 'MM-yyyy') from dbo.EOD`

Comment: @PrateekDaniels Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 5):

There might be a more graceful way to pull this off, but the below works.

```
Declare @dt datetime = GETDATE() 

SELECT LEFT('0' + CAST(MONTH(@dt) as varchar(2)),2)  + '-' + CAST(YEAR(@dt) as char(4))
```

btw my normal Date Conversion cheat sheet is [here](http://rdsrc.us/0WQlRn), but I'm not seeing MM-YYYY as one of the formats.

Comment: The correct would be RIGHT function, because when you're above September you'd want the two final numbers.

Answer (score 4):

```
  select [MM-YYYY] = right(convert(varchar(10),getdate(),105),7)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this but when I use varchar im not able to sort the date according to the year. for example say I transformed the date from 2015-04-20 05:54:59 to 04-2015, now, since this is in varchar format and say if there are more dates in the column where the dates were : 03-2011,06-2014. and if I sort this column, I will get the following: 03-2011,04-2015,06-2014. Sorting this varchar column doesn't sort the date column.

Answer (score 3):

As you are using SQL Server 2014, You can use `FORMAT` which is the best also you can apply this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),MONTH(yourDateTimeField)) + '-' + 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(yourDateTimeField)) AS [MM-YYYY]
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY yourDateTimeField
```

Comment: I tried this but when I use varchar im not able to sort the date according to the year. for example say I transformed the date from 2015-04-20 05:54:59 to 04-2015, now, since this is in varchar format and say if there are more dates in the column where the dates were : 03-2011,06-2014. and if I sort this column, I will get the following: 03-2011,04-2015,06-2014. Sorting this varchar column doesn't sort the date column.

Comment: You just need to sort it based on your datetime field and display it as MM-YYYY. See my updated asnwer.