# How to convert MMYYYY (042011) to date and find datediff for todays date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `varchar` column with data like 042011 MMYYYY format. I want to convert this to find the gap from todays date to that column.

I want a answer like 2.2 years or something related.

I've tried

```
SELECT datediff(month,FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MM') + FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy'),'042011')
```

Comment: Improve you question please. Where is your SQL code that you tried?

Comment: @sharan that gives `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: You will always have more consistent results that work anywhere in the world if you use yyyymmdd

Comment: @TomC its a very old production table,cant change

Comment: how can you expect to find the gap, when there is no day in your value ? It can be 1 to 30 days off

Comment: SELECT datediff(year,CONVERT(DATETIME,(FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMM')+'01'),103),CONVERT(DATETIME,'20110401',103))

Comment: @guidoG why not months gaps?

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842873/convert-sql-server-date-to-mm-yyyy

Comment: @sharan what if you are at day 1 in a month, count the whole month ?

Comment: @sharan, you can get month gap but then you have to do some calculations to get that xx.x years sort of output.

Comment: @RandomCoder Tried already 
SELECT FORMAT(cast('042011' as date), 'mmyyyy')

Comment: @Sharan `MMYYYY` is not a date.You can't have a date without a month day. Why do you need it?

Comment: @sharan What are you trying to do? Explain your actual problem in the question, not how you think it can be solved. If you want calculate aggregations per month or any other period, it's a *lot* easier to join with a Calendar table, ie a table with eg 20-50 years worth of dates with extra fields for year, month, month day, week number, business reporting periods etc. Aggregates per month become a simple `GROUP BY Year, Month`. Month to day, Year to day, year over year etc become simple joins and filters on the Year or month columns

Comment: @sharan one of those extra fields can *easily* be an `MMYYYY` string you could use for joining. This way you won't have to parse anything, just join with the Calendar table on that column and perform whatever aggregation you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this?

```
SELECT ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF (month,CAST(RIGHT ('042011',4) + '-' + LEFT ('042011',2) + '-' + '01' AS DATE),CAST(GETDATE () AS DATE)) AS FLOAT) / CAST(12 AS FLOAT),2)
```

Result: 8.2

I set your varchar column to dateformat (2011-04-01) I add a default day (1) then get its month timediff to currentdate and divide the month to 12 to get the number of years. Also done some float casting and rounding up to get desired result.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: @sharan have you tested this query with 012011? I mean by passing different months?

Comment: @sharan please test this with months from 1 to 12 and check if this is really what you want ? This does returns result different from your question in my opion

Comment: @GuidoG No, you can try it yourself. You may try it 062019.

Comment: 022011 and 032011 both return the same difference for example

Comment: maybe he did not test with more than one month

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194418/discussion-between-jervs-and-guidog).

Comment: @sharan I added edited the round to 2 decimal places so you can see the difference.

Comment: @GuidoG I get it. There's nothing wrong with my answer it's just we can't see the difference in 1 decimal place.

Answer (score 2):

`MMYYYY` is not a date as it doesn't contain the month day. I suspect it's a string that refers to a specific reporting period.

The typical way of handling such periods is to use a [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/), with eg 20 or 50 years worth of dates and extra fields for year, month, day of month, week numbers, month names and most importantly, business reporting periods.

This table makes aggregations per period, or comparing different periods a lot easier and faster. Adding indexes on the various columns columns for very fast joins and groupings based on years, etc.

Assuming the Calendar table looks a bit like this :

```
create table Calendar
(
    Date DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Year int NOT NULL
    Month int not null,
    ....
    MonthLabel char(6),
    IX_Calendar_Year (Year),
    ....
    IX_Calendar_MonthLabel (MonthLabel),
)
```

You can calculate eg sums per month with :

```
select Year,Month,SUM(Total) as Total
From Orders inner join Calendar 
    on Calendar.Date=Orders.Date
group by Year, Month
```

Working with reporting periods is just as easy :

```
select MonthLabel,SUM(Total) as Total
From Orders inner join Calendar 
    on Calendar.Date=Orders.Date
group by MonthLabel
```

If the source data contains the reporting period label, you can join on that column :

```
select MonthLabel,SUM(Total) as Total
From Orders inner join Calendar 
    on Calendar.MonthLabel=Orders.MonthLabel
```

If the label comes from the UI, eg a reporting tool :

```
select Year,Month,SUM(Total) as Total
From Orders inner join Calendar 
    on Calendar.Date=Orders.Date
WHERE MonthLabel=@thatLabel
group by Year, Month
```

All these queries are *fast* because they involve no parsing and the join, grouping, filtering operations use indexed columns

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is next statement.

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Dates (
    MmYyyy varchar(6)
)
INSERT INTO #Dates 
    (Mmyyyy)
VALUES
    ('042011'),
    ('052011'),
    ('062011')
```

T-SQL:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    DATEDIFF(month,TRY_CONVERT(date, CONCAT(RIGHT(MmYyyy, 4), LEFT(MmYyyy, 2), '01')), GETDATE()) / 12, 
    ' y, ',
    DATEDIFF(month,TRY_CONVERT(date, CONCAT(RIGHT(MmYyyy, 4), LEFT(MmYyyy, 2), '01')), GETDATE()) % 12,
    ' m'
) AS [Difference]
FROM #Dates
```

Output:

```
Difference
8 y, 2 m
8 y, 1 m
8 y, 0 m
```

Notes:

About *"I want an answer like 2.2 years or something related"* in your question. If you want correct results, the calculation should be `years and months`, not `years and months / 12`. Just see next sample script - there are equal differences for 3 and 4 months, and for 9 and 10 months. Rounding to more than 1 decimal position makes the resul difficult to understand.

```
SELECT CONVERT(numeric(10, 1), v.Nmr / 12.0) AS [Difference]
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)) v(Nmr)

Difference
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.8
0.9
1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(
    month, 
    GETDATE(), 
    PARSE(
        CONCAT(
            RIGHT('042011', 4),'-',LEFT('042011', 2)) as date USING 'en-US'))
```

output

```
-98
```

means 98 months ago

Answer (score 0):

lets build this step by step so you can follow the logic

```
declare @value varchar(6) = '042011'
declare @datestring varchar(8)
declare @date date

-- convert your format to a regional independant format including day 1
select @datestring = concat(right(@value, 4), left(@value, 2), '01')

-- convert this into a valid date type
select @date = convert(date, @datestring)

-- now we can get the difference, first the years and then the months
select  datediff(month, @date, getdate()) / 12 as years,
        datediff(month, @date, getdate()) % 12 as months
```

all together it looks like this

```
select datediff(month, convert(date, (concat(right(@value, 4), left(@value, 2), '01'))), getdate()) / 12 as years,
       datediff(month, convert(date, (concat(right(@value, 4), left(@value, 2), '01'))), getdate()) % 12 as months
```

where @value can be substituted by the column of your table

for example how this looks in a query

```
declare @table table (value varchar(8))
insert into @table (value) 
values ('012011'), ('022011'), ('032011'), ('042011'), ('052011'), ('062011'), ('072011'), ('082011'), ('092011'), ('102011'), ('112011'), ('122011')

select value,
       datediff(month, convert(date, (concat(right(value, 4), left(value, 2), '01'))), getdate()) / 12 as years,
       datediff(month, convert(date, (concat(right(value, 4), left(value, 2), '01'))), getdate()) % 12 as months
from   @table
```

the result is `(getdate() returned 20190604 on the time of writing this)`

```
value   years   months  
-----   -----   ------  
012011  8        5  
022011  8        4  
032011  8        3  
042011  8        2  
052011  8        1  
062011  8        0  
072011  7       11  
082011  7       10  
092011  7        9  
102011  7        8  
112011  7        7  
122011  7        6
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the code is messy. But you can write a function for it.

Try this:

```
SELECT cast(datediff(year,CONVERT(DATETIME,'20110301',103),CONVERT(DATETIME,(FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMM')+'01'),103)) as varchar)+'.'+
cast((datediff(month,CONVERT(DATETIME,'20110301',103),CONVERT(DATETIME,(FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMM')+'01'),103)) -(datediff(year,CONVERT(DATETIME,'20110301',103),CONVERT(DATETIME,(FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMM')+'01'),103))*12)) as varchar)
```

Or

If you want to do it through function, the body will look something like this:

```
Declare @currentdate;
Declare @datetocompare varchar(10);
Declare @years varchar(10);
Declare @months varchar(10);

set @datetocompare='20110401';

set @currentdate=GETDATE();

select @years=datediff(year,CONVERT(DATETIME,@datetocompare,103),@currentdate);

select @months=datediff(month,CONVERT(DATETIME,@datetocompare,103),@currentdate)-(datediff(year,CONVERT(DATETIME,@datetocompare,103),@currentdate)*12);

select @years  +'.' +@months +' Years' asYearMonthDay;
```